# What iphone-php login system?

Tags: php, iphone, session, authentication

I'm a fresh iphone developer and i'm developing now an iphone app for a php app system.

I made a the login for users of the system on iPhone, i need to ask for how can i keep or store the user_id of logged in user on all app screens to get the data of the php system by using this user_id??

Please i need your help
thanks

Answer (score 1):

cookies? http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Session?. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: that's right if i need to know about sessions and cookies on php,
but i need to know how can i do that on i phone

Comment: Depend the object that you are using for to realize the connection (for example HTTPResponse class). But all are based into send a cookie and receive a cookie.  When PHP generate a new session then it return a new cookie (phpsessid), your application must read this cookie and send it back for subsequents calls.